# How much energy is in a 75 kg human being? Including atomic and electrical (charge)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, atomic-physics, charge, estimation

To calculate the energy in 75 kg of mass is easy with E = mc2. But, how to calculate how much charge are in all our atoms? It is, too, a gargantuan amount of energy.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the atoms and molecules in our bodies are held together by the electromagnetic force, and the energy associated with that interaction contributes to the mass of our bodies (as dictated by Einstein's $E = mc^2$ relation).

However, by far the biggest contributor to the mass of a human being (or any other common, macroscopic object for that matter) is the strong interaction: something like 98% of its mass comes from that force. You can read more about it [here](http://www.fnal.gov/pub/today/archive/archive_2012/today12-01-13_NutshellMassReadMore.html) and [here](https://axelmaas.blogspot.com/2011/10/mass-from-strong-force.html).

With that in mind, we can make a few simple calculations to get an estimate of the contribution of the electromagnetic interaction. Since about 98% of the mass comes from the strong force, we only have to explain the remaining ~2%, which amounts to 1.5kg for a 75kg body.

Now, the number of nucleons in our body is roughly given by $$N_{nuc} \approx m_{body} / m_{nuc} $$ with $m_{nuc} \approx 1.673 \times 10^{-27} \textrm{kg}$ (the mass of a proton/neutron - which includes the contribution of the strong interaction).

As a consequence, our bodies contain roughly $3 N_{nuc}$ quarks, about half of which are up quarks and the other half down quarks (the ratio is not exactly 1:1, but for the sake of this calculation that approximation will suffice). Thus, the average mass of a quark in an our body is $m_{quark} \approx 6.5 \times 10^{-30} \textrm{kg}$.

Finally, the contribution of the rest masses of all quarks is given by $$m_{quark}^{Tot} \approx 3 N_{nuc} m_{quark} \approx 0.8 \textrm{kg}$$

So, for a 75kg body, around 73.5kg come from the strong force and roughly 1kg comes from the rest mass of quarks. The remaining contributions include the rest mass of electrons, their kinetic energies, and, *at last*, the energy of the electromagnetic interaction. I'm not sure what's the relative weight of these various factors, but at least you have an upper bound: **for a 75kg body, the contribution of the electromagnetic force does not exceed 500g.**

Answer (score 0):

Human beings have no net charge, for each proton there is an electron. Protons and electrons have the same charge magnitude, but opposite value. It does not make sense to count the number of particles with positive charge and the particles with negative charge, or to say that a body has "$x$ possitive charge and $y$ negative charge". If the particles with possitive and negative charge are distributed uniformly, we can treat the body as if it had zero charge density, and therefore zero charge.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, that the net charge is 0. But it is not the same "1 - 1 = 0", than "1000000 - 1000000 = 0". There is charge, even if it is leveled.

Comment: Regarding charge, 1-1 is indeed equal to 100000-100000. However, if for any reason you are interested in counting only the particles with positive charge, you can make a qualitative calculation. If we suppose that all the mass comes from the protons, you can divide the total mass with the mass of a proton. This will give you the total number of protons. Multiplying this number by the charge of a proton will give you the "charge of positive particles".

Answer (score 0):

The electrical energy of atoms is tiny compared with their mass-energy. Consider a hydrogen atom. The electrostatic potential energy between the proton and the electron is just -27.2 eV, but the mass-energy of the electron is 511,000 eV and the mass-energy of the proton is a whopping 938,000,000 eV. So the mass-energy of a hydrogen atom is on the order of 30 million times larger than its electrical energy.

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers. I will study them all, there are a lot of things I didn´t know or remember.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of mass-energy of the nuclei and electrons in a human body absolutely dwarfs literally any other source of energy. For example, the mass-energy of a proton (938 MeV) is roughly a hundred million times more than the energy binding an electron to a proton in a hydrogen atom (13.6 eV), and roughly a billion times more than the energy binding atoms together in molecules (around 1 eV). As such, the amount of energy expended by taking apart the molecules and then taking apart the atoms is completely and utterly insignificant compared to the amount of mass-energy in the protons and electrons themselves. So, unless you want answers correct to one part per million or so, simply applying $E=mc^2$ will be sufficient.

Comment: But the rest mass already includes all the chemical binding energy, etc.